# Android: App freezes when using handler and switch

Tags: java, android, loops, while-loop

I want to repeat function every 500 milliseconds while switch is on. But when i run my code, everything freezes when i set switch on. Here is my code:

```
    mySwitch.setChecked(false);
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                pom = true;
                while (pom) {
                    final Handler h = new Handler();
                    final int delay = 1000;

                    h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            myClient.SendData("AA");
                            h.postDelayed(this, delay);
                        }
                    }, delay);
                }
            }
            else{
                pom = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

I have tried this too, now my app doesnt freeze, now it crashes down:

```
    mySwitch.setChecked(false);
    mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                pom = true;
                while (pom) {
                    int delay = 0; // delay for 0 sec.
                    int period = 500; // repeat every 10 sec.
                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            myClient.SendData("AA");
                        }
                    }, delay, period);
                }
            }
            else{
                pom = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you have to set pom to false or use break from **inside** the while loop. What are you trying to do, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are stuck in an infinite loop here.

```
while (pom) {
                final Handler h = new Handler();
                final int delay = 1000;

                h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        myClient.SendData("AA");
                        h.postDelayed(this, delay);
                    }
                }, delay);
            }
```

The program is not able to get out of this loop because the pom is always true.
And it stops responding.

This will solve your problem:
Save the state of switch in sharedPreferences and post the Runnable anywhere in activity. Send Data only when the value in sharedPreferences is true.

Comment: But how can I stop it when switch is off?

Comment: Edited the answer. Check now.

Comment: Accept this as answer if you're satisfied with the solution :)